# HTML support in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: html, visual-studio-express

I'm using the C# package of Visual Studio 2010 Express. I want to add an HTML file to my project, but the C# package doesn't seem to have HTML support (e.g. syntax highlighting) included.

I tried installing the Web Developer package hoping it would simply add features to my existing installation. Turned out that they are acting like different programs though. Still no HTML features.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Check this related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577/syntax-highlighting-for-html-markup-disappears-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: The Express versions of the Visual Studio IDEs are in fact different programs. So yeah...

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is edit some HTML and want highlighting, may I suggest a free advanced text editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ?